# How to scan from flatbed scanner using delphi twain component?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am performing scanning using DelphiTwain component in Delphi7 .Problem is that if scanner is multifunctional (ie having Flatbed and feeder) and both flatbed and feeder load with page.Now when I try to scan from flatbed it automatically scan from feeder. My scanning code is ,

```
 If cmbScanningMode.Text = 'Doc Feeder' Then
 Begin
   DelphiTwain1.Source[twainSource].GetFeederEnabled(flgLoaded);
   If flgLoaded Then
   Begin`enter code here`
     DelphiTwain1.Source[twainSource].SetFeederEnabled(True);
     DelphiTwain1.Source[twainSource].SetAutoFeed(True);
   End
   Else //If not flgLoaded then
   Begin
     ShowMessage('Please insert document in feeder');
     DelphiTwain1.UnloadLibrary;
     scanState := 'NoPage';
     Break;
   End
 Else If cmbScanningMode.Text = 'Flatbed' Then
 Begin
   DelphiTwain1.Source[twainSource].SetFeederEnabled(False);
   DelphiTwain1.Source[twainSource].SetAutoFeed(False);
 End;
```

Comment: Are you sure it's not a sensor stuck on the scanner which makes it always think there's something in the feeder? Because it's the scanner's duty to take care of that, not the software.

Comment: Does your code really execute the `SetFeederEnabled(False)`? Try tracing if it gets to that part. If so, does scanning from flatbed from the standard software work if both options are loaded with paper? Maybe the feeder has always priority.

Comment: SetFeederEnabled(False) is not working and hence if both options are loaded then by default scanner scan from feeder even if you selected scanning from flatbed.

Comment: I meant, if you load both options and scan from the standard included software you got with the scanner. Can you then select the flatbed and scan from it while the feeder is loaded? (I understand it does not work from your software so i want to know if can work at all, like with the included software of the scanner)